# Spring IoC: depends-on overrides lazy-init

Tags: java, spring

A prototypical portion of an application context:

```
<bean id="option_A" class="class_a" lazy-init="true"/>
<bean id="option_B" class="class_b" lazy-init="true" depends-on="setup_bean"/>
<alias name="option_${OPTION_PROPERTY}" alias="thingChosen"/>
<bean id="setup_bean" class="class_setup" lazy-init="true"/>
```

The concept here is that if OPTION_PROPERTY is set to "A", then

```
<bean id="foo" class="whatever"><property name="bar" ref="thingChosen"/></bean>
```

will get an instance of class_a injected into the bar property, and if the property is set to "B", then it will get an instance of class b injected, but class b has a hidden dependency on setup_bean (which class a lacks), so setup_bean must be created first.

What is happening is that if OPTION_PROPERTY is set to "A", then setup_bean is still created. I've tried this using Spring 3.2.4.RELEASE, and it's consistent. This seems like either a bug or a misunderstanding on my part.

If a bean is lazy-init, then shouldn't depends-on beans wait until that bean is lazily created before being created themselves?

Answer (score 2):

> If a bean is lazy-init, then shouldn't depends-on beans wait until
>   that bean is lazily created before being created themselves?

Yes. In other words `option_B` will not be created until `setup_bean` is requested and initialized. If `option_B` is requested first, then that will force `setup_bean` to be initialized first.

[The documentation says](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lazy-init)

> However, when a lazy-initialized bean is a dependency of a singleton
>   bean that is not lazy-initialized, the ApplicationContext creates the
>   lazy-initialized bean at startup, because it must satisfy the
>   singleton's dependencies.

Therefore, this bean declaration

```
<bean id="foo" class="whatever"><property name="bar" ref="thingChosen"/></bean>
```

will force the initialization of `thingChosen`, which in this case is aliasing `option_A`.

I cannot reproduce what you are experiencing (and should not). Double check what you are doing. Maybe another bean is referencing `setup_bean`.

Here's an SSCCE

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
        System.out.println("context initialized");
        context.getBean("shouldnot");
    }
    public static class MyClass {
        public MyClass() {
            System.out.println("myclass");
        }
    }   
    public static class SetupBean {
        public SetupBean() {
            System.out.println("setup");
        }
    }
    public static class MyOtherClass {
        private MyClass myClass;
        public MyOtherClass() {
            System.out.println("myotherclass");
        }
        public MyClass getMyClass() {
            return myClass;
        }
        public void setMyClass(MyClass myClass) {
            this.myClass = myClass;
        }
    }
}
```

and `spring.xml` beans

```
<bean id="myref" class="test.Test$MyClass" lazy-init="true"></bean>
<bean id="shouldnot" class="test.Test$MyClass" lazy-init="true" depends-on="setup_bean"></bean>

<bean class="test.Test$MyOtherClass" >
    <property name="myClass" ref="myref"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="setup_bean" class="test.Test$SetupBean" lazy-init="true"></bean>
```

it prints (minus Spring logs)

```
myotherclass
myclass
context initialized
setup
myclass
```

In other words, `setup` is only created when `shouldnot` is requested.

Comment: That is a fairly comprehensive proof. I will go back over my code and see if I can discern any other conceivable reason my "setup_bean" may be called into play. I don't suppose the <alias> has anything to do with it? I'm using that trick to effectively perform if/else logic in the context.

Comment: @nsayer Scanning through the docs I don't see anything pointing to such a conclusion about aliasing. Anyway, it resolves to `option_A`.

Comment: @nsayer I'm not sure what your `if-else` applies to, but you're probably better off using `Profiles`.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that elsewhere in the context, there's this little gem:

```
<context:annotation-config />
```

This, it appears, results in lazy-init being ignored.

Trying to figure out how the exclusion machinery works is the next step, but is out-of-scope for this question.

Comment: On its own, this is not enough. You must have some annotation that is forcing beans to be injected.